# How to clear the listbox after deletion of item using sqlite in windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am trying to clear and reload  the listbox after deletion of item .but i am getting error.
Please tell me how to clear and reload the listbox after sqlite delete operation in windows phone 7.

```
int _id = int.Parse(((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(e.OriginalSource)).Tag.ToString());
                string strDel = "Delete from category where id=" + _id;
                (Application.Current as App).db.Delete<Category>(strDel);
                ApplicationsListBox.Items.Clear();
                LoadData();
```

Error:Operation not supported on read-only collection.

Please any one tell me how to clear and reload the listbox....

Comment: How are you doing your databind?

Answer (score 0):

The Items collection on a ListBox is readonly. Try using the ItemsSource property.